# relative url not working for getheaders

Tags: php, get-headers

here is this script which works just fine for absolute url in img src tag but if img src tag is having relative url it fails and give error

`Warning: get_headers() [function.get-headers]`: This function may only be used against URLs in 
  in first link img src is relative url but in second link img src is absolute url and it gives perfect result but i want my script to work in both cases any idea??

```
<?php
$websitelink = 'http://img172.imagevenue.com/img.php?image=90465_Gwen3_122_17lo.jpg';

//  $websitelink='http://www.santabanta.com/bollywood/76432/whoa-after-200-crore-now-dhoom-3-races-for-rs-300-crore-mark/';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $websitelink);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$resulty = curl_exec($ch);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($resulty);
$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $data = get_headers($tag->getAttribute('src'), 1);
    if ((intval($data["Content-Length"])) >= 30720) {
        $op7 = '' . $tag->getAttribute('src') . '';
        echo $op7 . '</br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you're loading this stuff from a PHP file, it's probably doing it in relation to that file and not the HTML doc (I mean unless they're the same file).

Answer (score 2):

The function `get_headers` will actually *perform* a `HTTP GET` request, therefore it needs a fully qualified address, and cannot work if you specify only a relative URL.

You will have to infer what's the complete address to the image you're trying to load.

Comment: that i know but how to convert that relative url to absolute url is the question